# how to load images according to the value coming using if condition in anguilarjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

im  trying to show occupied and vacant images according the value . if value more than 3.50 it should display image1 if its equal or less than 3.50 show image 2.
i tried this code but im unble to find where i did mistake. im not getting any image.

code

```
 <td><img ng-if ng-src="{{getSlotImage(parkingslot1)}}" /></td>
    <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('https://example.com', {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic 23456==' }
                })
                   .then(function (response) {
                       $scope.names = response.data;
                       $scope.decodedFrame = atob($scope.names.dataFrame);
                       $scope.decodedFrameNew = $scope.decodedFrame.substring(4);
                       $scope.distanceinFeet = 835 * 0.95;
                       $scope.Value = $scope.distanceinFeet / 148;
                       $scope.parkingslot1 = $scope.Value.toFixed(2);
                       $scope.names.timestamp = new Date($scope.names.timestamp).toLocaleString(); // Parse the date to a localized string
                   });

                $scope.getSlotImage = function (slot) {
                                       var imageUrl = slot > 3.5 ? 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-9/256/Accept-icon.png' :
                            'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Cancel.png';


                    return imageUrl;


                }
                });


        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ng-if attribute in  tag

Comment: but first it loads second image than first image. why 2 images loading???loading cancel image than again access image showing..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/7199651/swapna this is because it by default loads cancel image at first and when http loads data it then calculates the correct value